# Error: aggregate 'uuid_t uu' has incomplete type and cannot be defined

Tags: linux, uuid

I am installing `OpenDAP` in a Fedora (release 20). `OpenDAP` depends on `UUID`, so I installed `uuid-devel` and its dependencies. When I compiled `OpenDAP`, I encountered the following error:

```
DODSFilter.cc:895:12: error: aggregate 'uuid_t uu' has incomplete type and cannot be defined
     uuid_t uu;
        ^
DODSFilter.cc:896:21: error: 'uuid_generate' was not declared in this scope
     uuid_generate(uu);
                 ^
DODSFilter.cc:898:30: error: 'uuid_unparse' was not declared in this scope
     uuid_unparse(uu, &uuid[0]);
```

Any idea? Other Linux distributions do not have this problem.

Comment: I just used `UUID` in `e2fsprogs`.

Comment: please edit your question instead of adding comments

Comment: Most distributions (at least Debian based) offer some `uuid-dev` package. You should find the equivalent one for Fedora (e.g. some [libuuid-devel](http://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libuuid-devel)). And UUID is not specific to e2fsprogs

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem installing libdap-3.20.4 in Fedora 30.

I have installed libuuid, libuuid-devel, uuid, uuid-devel but this problem still exist. I search the String `uuid` in my filesystem, found that there are two `uuid.h` files. They are `/usr/include/uuid.h` and `/usr/include/uuid/uuid.h`(`uuid_generate` and `uuid_unparse` are in this file). So I repalced `/usr/include/uuid.h` with `/usr/include/uuid/uuid.h` and it works. Hope this may help you.